# How to use "display-buffer-no-window" with "display-buffer-alist"

Tags: display-buffer-alist

I wrote a simple function for Emacs that ends in calling `async-shell-command` with a music player.  All good so far, but the command pops up the standard-out buffer.

Its help text reads (among other things):

```
To run COMMAND without displaying the output
in a window you can configure ‘display-buffer-alist’ to use the action
‘display-buffer-no-window’ for the buffer ‘*Async Shell Command*’.
```

Trying to get this override set temporary for calling the command, I used `let` to define `display-buffer-alist`.  While the buffer does not pop up anymore, I get an error in the messages related around `display-buffer-assq-regexp` every time:

```
display-buffer-assq-regexp: Wrong type argument: integerp, (nil (allow-no-window . t))
```

Depending on what I tried, this also came up with:

```
display-buffer-assq-regexp: Wrong number of arguments: #<subr regexp-quote>, 2
```

I searched the entire built-in Emacs documentation for `display-buffer-alist` as well as for `display-buffer-no-window`, but trying as I might, I cannot get rid of the error message.

With the notoriously sparse documentation, I kindly ask if anyone can point me to or provide me an example on how to use the advice provided in the help text of `async-shell-command`:

How do I use `display-buffer-no-window` to "fill" `display-buffer-alist` without generating errors?

**EDIT**

Added code:

```el
(defun music-player ()
  "Starts a music player with a randomized (shuffled) list of all songs"
  (interactive)
  (let ((sPlayer          "/usr/bin/mpv")
        (lPlayerArguments '("--player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui" "--volume=50" "--playlist="))
        (lMusic           (directory-files-recursively (concat (getenv "HOME") "/Media/Music") "\\.mp3$\\|\\.m4a$"))
        (sPlaylist        (concat (getenv "HOME") "/Media/Music/play.list")))
    (unless (get-buffer sPlaylist)
      (create-file-buffer sPlaylist))
    (set-buffer (concat (file-name-base sPlaylist) (file-name-extension sPlaylist t)))
    (erase-buffer)
    (insert (mapconcat 'identity lMusic "\n"))
    (shell-command-on-region (buffer-end -1) (buffer-end 1) "shuf" (concat (file-name-base sPlaylist) (file-name-extension sPlaylist t)) t)
    (write-file sPlaylist)
    (kill-buffer (concat (file-name-base sPlaylist) (file-name-extension sPlaylist t)))
    (let ((lProgramBuffers '("*Player stdout*" "*Player stderr*")))
      (create-file-buffer (nth 0 lProgramBuffers))
      (create-file-buffer (nth 1 lProgramBuffers))
      (let ((display-buffer-alist
             '((substring-no-properties (regexp-quote (nth 0 lProgramBuffers)))
               (display-buffer-no-window (nth 0 lProgramBuffers) display-buffer-alist))))
        (async-shell-command
         (concat sPlayer " " (mapconcat 'identity lPlayerArguments " ") "\"" sPlaylist "\"")
         (nth 0 lProgramBuffers) (nth 1 lProgramBuffers))))))
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @phils, while the question was more aimed on how to follow the manual's advice (independent on the background), I now added the code.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: `let`-binding `display-buffer-alist` will only affect the synchronous parts of your call to `async-shell-command`.  The binding will no longer be in effect by the time the asynchronous process finishes, so you need to be sure that's sufficient.  I'm not sure I've ever seen someone `let`-bind `display-buffer-alist` before.

Comment: The appearance of `display-buffer-alist` in your ACTION value looks really wrong.  What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Oh, and you're not evaluating `(substring-no-properties...)` so your CONDITION is neither a regexp nor a function.

Comment: "What are you trying to do there?" - This is likely the result of the non-explanatory manual when I tried to look up both `display-buffer-alist` and `display-buffer-no-window` and then tried my best to put them together.  It describes the synopsis as `(display-buffer-no-window BUFFER ALIST)`, but poorly explains what ALIST should contain.  Is there a complete glossary even explaining what an ALIST is and how it should look like?  Looking through existing code I have plus your example in the answer, it appears that the basic principle of an ALIST is a list containing `'((key . value) ...)`.

Comment: The `(substring-no-properties)` function I added since it complained about the regex.  So, I tried to "flatten" it as a string.  Obviously to no avail.  At first I simply had `(nth 0 lProgramBuffers)` and then tried other variants depending on the error message I received.

Comment: `C-h i g (elisp)Buffer Display Action Alists` describes the `ALIST` arguments.

Comment: Because your `'((substring-no-properties (regexp-quote (nth 0 lProgramBuffers))) ...` was quoted, `(substring-no-properties (regexp-quote (nth 0 lProgramBuffers)))` is not evaluated -- you're not calling those functions at all.  The argument needs to be a regexp string or a function object, and it's neither -- instead it's a list containing your would-be code `(substring-no-properties (regexp-quote (nth 0 lProgramBuffers)))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe want this:

```el
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             (cons (lambda (bufname _action)
                     (string= bufname (nth 0 lProgramBuffers)))
                   (cons 'display-buffer-no-window
                         '((allow-no-window . t)))))
```

Comment: Thanks!  It does appear to work.  Though mind to explain its contents, please?  I prefer to use code I understand in the event that I need to make amendments.

Comment: If you read `C-h v display-buffer-alist` again in the context of this code, you should be able to figure it out.  The cons cells are providing the `(CONDITION . (FUNCTIONS . ALIST))` structure.

Comment: Unfortunately I fail to understand the `lambda` function in your implementation.  To my understanding `lambda` is a nameless function, but I cannot see where from "bufname" as well as "_action" is fed and when testing it isolated in "*scratch*" it produces a more complex result than I expected and cannot backtrace it completely.  With that understanding the remainder is not as trivial.

Comment: I marked the answer as solution to the problem I had since implementing it as is (a.k.a. copy'n'paste) worked.  However, the ultimate goal of my question was to learn how to add valid elements to `display-buffer-alist` in a way that I can reproduce them.  This I still cannot as I do not know how to properly create and format a condition even after dissecting the construct presented.

Comment: The documentation I pointed you to reads "CONDITION is either a regexp matching buffer names, or a function that takes two arguments - a buffer name and the ACTION argument of 'display-buffer' - and returns a boolean."  The underscore prefix of the _action arg indicates to the byte compiler (and the programmer) that it's intentional that the argument isn't used by the function.

Comment: n.b. The reason the documentation for this feature is fairly substantial and complicated is because there's a lot going on -- if it could all be trivially explained in a few paragraphs, it would be.  I don't think you're going to get an answer which makes it all suddenly seem simple.

Comment: If it wasn't clear, though, this basic structure says "When CONDITION is true, then display the buffer using FUNCTIONS in conjunction with the properties specified in ALIST".  Here the lambda provides the condition; `display-buffer-no-window` is the function(s) to use; and the alist is supplying the 'allow-no-window' value which is understood by `display-buffer-no-window`.

Comment: We *could* have used a regexp for the CONDITION, but then if you subsequently modified your `lProgramBuffers` list the regexp might be wrong, whereas the function condition is always comparing against the current value.

Comment: Thanks!  I have extensive experience with shell scripting (bash) as well as PHP (and a bit longer ago Visual Basic).  So, I generally know what a condition is and how it works.  Likewise I have been through their respective documentation.  However, trying to get into ELisp proved so far an uphill battle out of lack of examples chiefly, but also due to the way the manual is written.  Whenever I turn for help here, I usually have read the section of the manual several times over as well as already looked online for solutions/examples.  So, my apologies if all this seems trivial to you.

Comment: With more background, the docs will make more sense.  I highly recommend working through `C-h i g (eintr)`.  I expect you'll know some things already, but that you'll learn a lot of things you didn't understand before, and that it will help you to understand other docs in future.

Comment: I totally agree and I tried so far to get the hang of it by simply trying on my own as much as possible.  Unfortunately, there are points where the help is not so helpful and lacks cross-references to other sections not easily found otherwise or is not self-explanatory while stuck within a certain problem.  Thanks for the info page(s)!  In retrospect I now even know that it can be found using the scenic route under "Help" > "More Manuals" > "Introduction to Emacs Lisp".  It shall keep me company to learn more.